# How to create custom user in Django rest framework without a password?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, backend

I'm working on a project where I have to create a custom user with email address and other details but **not a password**, instead of a password, I want to use OTP. I have searched through the web and haven't found a decent source which can help me with it.

What I want is -

- To create a custom user manager in DRF
- To create a superuser without a password (using OTP for that instead)
- Create a user similarly

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: To login your user with OTP you've to write custom [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#customizing-authentication-in-django) and to create custom user check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)

Answer (score 0):

1.First create user in the default User table or u can just create this user by dynamically after recieving the email from front end.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    user = User()
    user.email = "specific user email(user1@example.com)"
    user.save()
```

2.Create an OTP table with OTP column and a user foriegn key column

3.When the user try to login, using AJAX recieve the email id to send the otp.After recieving email id generate an OTP and send email to the corresponding email.

4.Save the OTP generated in the OTP table by using foriegn key for user and otp column

```
OTP TABLE
otp     user
1234    foriegnkey of user
```

5.After entering the OTP by the user verify it by user email with OTP in the OTP table

6.If valid login using 'login(request,user(object))'

Comment: But in the first step mentioned if I create the user using the default User table wouldn't it ask for a password? and how will this help me create a superuser without password?

Comment: @MitangshuChatterjee if you are creating using UI it will ask password for every user.But if you are creating using a code you can create users without password(Not in case of super user i think it requires password)